# how to include by default in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I made a project using cmake(following providers instructions). it uses Qt. I noticed that classes like QString are recognized globally. even if I add a cpp file to project and use QString in it(without `#include "QString.h"`, there is no problem. it seems like that all files have QString.h and some other files included by default. how is that possible?

I tried to create a new project and copy the settings that I suspect might be the solution, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. thank you that's it. in the properties they forced to include a file. in that file they included all the files like `QString.h` and such